# Not able to add custom data-attributes to polymer elements using bound data

Tags: polymer, custom-data-attribute

Haven't been able to find a any answers to this, or existing questions.

When i try and add a user-id or any type of data attribute to an element it works fine if i use an arbitrary string. Soon and i use a data string the data attribute disappears completely from the element.

Anyone have some logical answer to why this happens? Heres an example where im trying to add the user id to the container so i can retrieve the selected user. "data-userid='{{item.user_id}}'"

```
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
        <div on-tap="_userClick" data-userid="{{item.user_id}}" class="user-contain">
            <user-display user-id="{{item.user_id}}" style="float:left;"></user-display>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Thanks guys n gals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To bind to data-* attributes you must use `$=` instead of plain `=`.

Example:

```
<div data-url$="{{myVal}}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, i knew this would be something so simple i missed. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To bind to data-* attributes you must use data-*$ instead of plain data-*.

Example:

```
<div data-url$ = "{{myVal}}"></div>
<div data-url$="{{myVal}}"></div>
```

These will not work:

```
<div data-url  $= "{{myVal}}"></div>
<div data-url="{{myVal}}"></div>
```

I don't know why a "$" is necessary, if someone can clarify the reason for this in the comments, I will be happy.

Comment: Please don't add follow-up questions as answer. Default is property binding, with `$` Polymer binds to an attribute.